# Updated FacobookLogin Pod, Got Error: No known class method for selector 'objectForJSONString:error:'

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-login

Recently I have updated the Below mentioned pods for FacebookLogin Button implemented in my app

```
pod 'FacebookCore'
pod 'FacebookLogin'
```

The versions of both pods are 0.7.0

I had updated the pods using the command

```
pod update
```

After updating the when I built the project there is an error in the path

> Pods/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/Internal/FBSDKLoginManagerLogger.m:163:60: No known class method for selector 'objectForJSONString:error:'

Both these errors is occurring in two places in the same class

> No known class method for selector 'objectForJSONString:error:'

```
NSDictionary<id, id> *clientState = [FBSDKBasicUtility objectForJSONString:parameters[FBSDKLoginManagerLoggingClientStateKey] error:NULL];
```

Comment: I think that after the updated pods the classes for the Facebook cannot be found so you would have to stick to the specific version of pod for Facebook or update your code according to latest Facebook SDK.

Comment: but I got a mail from facebook development to update to latest, because there are some privacy changes, that why I updated the pods @BhargavR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did my R&D, there was no solution. 
I solved it by just removing the entire FacebookLogin Pods,

```
#pod 'FacebookCore'
#pod 'FacebookLogin'
```

Then Built the project, and then re-installed the same pods with the latest version to 5.0, then the issue seems to solved.

Answer (score 6):

I had to change FBSDKBasicUtility to FBSDKInternalUtility. Xcode will prompt you to unlock the files to make the change.

Comment: This worked for me! Ended up making this change in FBSDKLoginMangerLogger.m and in FBSDKLoginCompletion.m and then got no complaints when calling objectForJSONString. Thanks for saving me some frustration! Much appreciated after a nearly sleepless night :-)

Answer (score 3):

I have also received a notification from Facebook to upgrade the Facebook SDK to 5.0.(Previously it was 4.39.0) Below is the link which shows the latest features of Facebook SDK :

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/upgrade-guide

If you want to use these then you have to update the SDK and at code level integrate new pods for Facebook as shown in the above link.

If you don't want to use these features then you have to restrict your pods to a specific version so in future `pod update` the Facebook pods are not changed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: tried this but didn't work, but I have solved the issue. I will post it as answer. thanks anyway..

Answer (score 1):

I had to use Xcode 10 to build an app to support older iOS versions. I would get this error when running to a device (but not a simulator). This error would go away once I started using Xcode 11 again.